# How to read char from standard input in Java

Tags: io, java

I have to read char(one at a time) from the standard input in Java.The input will consist of numerous lines **(each of about 10000 chars)**. I do not need to store the chars , they are processed when read.Also I need to skip the newline char .Can someone suggest me an efficient way to do this ?

Comment: Use `input.replaceAll()` method and replace whatever you want.

Comment: What U tried so far...

Comment: see/download the documentation http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html THEN ask that question and u wont get downvoted...its likely contained w/in a String Class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need something like this.
Replace the # with whatever appropriate.

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test022 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStreamReader br = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        char ch = ' ';
        while (true){
            ch = (char)br.read();
            if (ch == '#') break;
            else if (ch == '\n') continue;
            else if (ch == '\r') continue;

            System.out.println("Char read: " + ch);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I need to break the loop when it reads EOF . How is EOF denoted in java?

Comment: @piyukr It's the int value of (-1).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this will work:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Tester
{
    public static void main(String args[])
        throws IOException
    {
        int ch;
        while ((ch = System.in.read()) != -1)
        {
            if (ch != '\n' && ch != '\r')
            {
                processChar((char)ch);
            }
        }
    }


    private static void processChar(char c)
    {
        // do stuff
        System.out.println("Processing: '" + c + "'");
    }

}
```